# save compressed image vs compress image before rendering

Tags: django, database, http, nginx, server-side-rendering

I am developing a webapp and need to render images in different sizes, for that I have one option to save images in different sizes and then render whatever needs. It will save time of compression but takes more storage because I need to save 6 different sizes of same image.

Another one is compress image before rendering as per size needed, I am not sure but I think it will take more time to process and also takes more memory in ram. Is this make my ram overloaded ??

I want to go with second one but I think its bad.

Can anyone tell which method can be more useful in what case and what can be the more efficient technique for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right. Second option will take more memory and time to process these images will be more.

I would recommend to go with first option. If you are worried about storage then you always go with AWS S3 buckets. You can check out [AWS S3 Bucket Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) here.